# AMP page showing empty in google cache

Tags: amp-html

I have a strange issue with AMP pages. It's showing empty in google search on mobile where Google Cache displays the page.

Example Valid AMP Page: https://www.journaldev.com/2366/core-java-interview-questions-and-answers/amp

Looks perfectly fine when loaded in mobile browser, desktop browsers etc.

When I search for "core java interview questions" in mobile browser using Google, it shows the AMP page and when I click it then it's empty. See attached image.

[image: Empty Page]

How do I fix this? Even if I make some changes how do I tell google to refresh it's Cached page to see if it's fixed?
Even this page is also fine: https://www-journaldev-com.cdn.ampproject.org/c/s/www.journaldev.com/2366/core-java-interview-questions-and-answers/amp

The problem seems to be happening only in mobile google search where Google AMP Cache is served.

Comment: i have check working fine : https://www.google.co.in/amp/s/www.journaldev.com/2366/core-java-interview-questions-and-answers/amp

Comment: Did you went to page directly or through google search. Can you post an image if possible?

Comment: It was Cache issue, after clearning Cache it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

It was browser Cache issue, I cleared Chrome browser cache in mobile and it's working fine now. Hopefully helps someone facing this issue.